# How to implement Concurrent GetOrCreate with JPA session?

Tags: java, spring, session, jpa, transactions

I need to implement a GetOrCreate (i call it ensureExists) of an entity in a spring-jpa (hibernate) driven web application.
I have a layered application (WS/Services/DAL/Datastore) and I want to implement this functionality in the service layer (spring driven).
The basic idea is:

1. Find-entity
2. If found return it.
3. Otherwise persist the entity.
4. If all ok return it.
5. If a unique constraint violation has occurred try to lookup the entity again and return it.

The problem arises from the fact that once an exception is thrown the hibernate session should be closed and reopened (from Session's [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html)) which makes step 5 invalid, but I still want to encapsulate this logic in the service layer (and not have it reside in the DAL or WS).

I'd love to hear suggestions on how this can be solved, I have an idea but I'd like to hear some input before posting it as to not tilt the answers toward it.

Thanks in advance

**Update**
The solution I have in mind is as follows:
Refactor stage 3 into a package scoped service which has a single ensureExists method (with generics) which accepts the Dao of that type and the entity and has the propogation of `REQUIRES_NEW`. This method will try to persist and if fails will of course throw an exception which will be caught in the original service and it will try to persist if that exception has been thrown.
I'd love some feedback about how this can be implemented otherwise.
If no one will suggest otherwise in a couple of days I'll post this as an answer with a code sample and accept it.

Comment: I would do as you plan, except I would put steps 1 to 4 in a service with REQUIRES_NEW.

Comment: @JB Nizet Why do you think step 1,2,4 need to be in a transaction? And additionally it seems to me that logically only step 3 is in a different level of abstraction so there is some reason to having it sit in a different service. All other steps are of the same abstraction level (I think).

Comment: I just find it clearer to have a "getOrCreate" method, which can throw an exception, and that I can retry from the outside if I want to. It also decouples the retrying logic (which could be made completely generic, extracted to a proxy or interceptor) from the specific use-case. And it also allows doing something other with the created entity than just returning it. With your system, the entity you get is attached is found, and detached if created.

Answer (score 0):

To find entity you might use criteria api + reflection to populate all significant properties and search by sample object.
To resolve concurency problem consider pessimistic locking.
When you do load just put lock on that object and release this lock once all transaction is done.
Not sure if it would be the best choise regarding performance but you should never get exceptions here.

Comment: I may be wrong, but i think you won't be able to use pessimistic locking in case when the "find" step requires conditions (except for single column ones on indexed columns).

Comment: Thanks fury for your answer. I actually don't want to use pessimistic locking since it will be a performance killer. I think this is a classic usecase for optimistic locking but I just need to prepare for that end usecase